# Empty soup.findAll

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, anaconda, spyder

Beautiful Soup won't work as expected on this page. I need to get the table.

```
    page2="http://www.moneycontrol.com/stocks/marketinfo/marketcap/bse/banks-private-sector.html"
    soup2 = BeautifulSoup(page2.content,"lxml")
    for tablerow in soup2.findAll('td',class_="brdrgtgry"):
        print(tablerow.text)
```

Regards,
babsdoc

Comment: check if you don't need html5 support ( `soup2 = BeautifulSoup(page2.content,"html5lib")` instead of `soup2 = BeautifulSoup(page2.content,"lxml")` )

Answer (score 0):

Don't know what the rest of your code is doing, but the snippet that you've posted won't work. You would need to actually retrieve the page first.

so, adding

```
import requests
```

and

```
soup2 = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(page2).content, "lxml")
```

to your snippet allows me to yield

```
HDFC Bank




Add to Watchlist
Add to Portfolio




1,665.35
0.40
1,715.60
1,193.45
427,147.14
ICICI Bank
```

etc.

Comment: Hi Shawn,I have done all that. the problem is that the for loop for the findall statement is returning empty values

Comment: But it isn't the problem in my local implementation. I print values as shown in the post. So the page has data and the `findAll` is parsing the page.

Comment: Yes Shawn, thanks for your help. But something seems to be wrong at my end. I am getting either blanks or weird text which isn't a part of the page content. I will investigate this further.

Comment: your `findAll` is working fine. The code that you have presented is not capable of getting any data from the `page2`. There is no way for the content to be requested and retrieved.

Comment: What exactly do I have to request and retrieve?

Comment: @babsdoc What version of beautiful soup do you have? In bs4, the function is `find_all`.

Comment: I am testing the script on both BS3 and 4, the find_all also fails to fetch me the 'td' objects :(